# Swift Annotation click button

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have a mapView with a custom annotation. I also added a button to this but is there a way to see on which annotation the button was pressed?

Here is the code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView!.canShowCallout = true
        anView!.enabled = true


        anView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure) 

        let imageview_left = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))
        imageview_left.image = UIImage(named: "left.png")
        anView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imageview_left

        let imageview_right = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 13))
        imageview_right.image = UIImage(named: "right.png")
        anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = imageview_right

    }
    else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }


    let subtitleView = UILabel()
    subtitleView.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans-Light", size: 14)
    subtitleView.numberOfLines = 1
    subtitleView.text = annotation.subtitle!
    anView!.detailCalloutAccessoryView = subtitleView


    let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
    anView!.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

    return anView
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {

    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        print("Pressed!")

    }
    print("Click")
}
```

When I click on the rightCalloutAccessoryView nothing happens. When I click on the title or subtitle annotation nothing happens too. What I made wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you do that is to add a target to the button:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    // ...

    if anView == nil {
        // ... 
        let button = MyButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.showAnnotationDisclosure(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
    }

    return anView
}

func showAnnotationDisclosure(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Disclosure button clicked")
}
```

Now if you want to know what annotation was clicked, you have to subclass `UIButton`:

```
class MyButton : UIButton {
    var annotation: CustomPointAnnotation? = nil
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    // ...
    if anView == nil {
        // ...
        let button = MyButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.showAnnotationDisclosure(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
    }

    if let button = anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView as? MyButton {
        button.annotation = annotation
    }

    return anView
}

func showAnnotationDisclosure(sender: MyButton) {
    print("Disclosure button clicked")
    print(sender.annotation?.title)
}
```

Comment: It is working! Thank you, but I have an error with this code: button.annotation = annotation Error: Cannot assign value of type 'MKAnnotation' to type 'CustomPointAnnotation?' 
And of course I don't know what annotation was clicked.

Comment: Cast it to CustomPointAnnotation with as!

Comment: Thank you.             button.annotation = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation

Answer (score 0):

According to the apple docs the delegate methods for pressing `leftCalloutAccessoryView` or `rightCalloutAccessoryView` will only be called if they are descendants of `UIControl`

So either do that or handle the gestures yourself by adding e.g instances of `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the appropriate views.
Remember that if those are instances of `UIImageView` you also have to set `instance.userInteractionEnabled = true`

[docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/rightCalloutAccessoryView)